# SSRS: Using exists condition in sql where clause while passing values from SSRS Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

```
Table : incident
----------------
incident_id   usr_id    item_id   Inc_Date
10059926       191       61006    8-22-2015
10054444       222        3232    6-7-2015

Table: act_reg
--------------
 act_reg_id  act_type_id  incident_id    usr_id  act_type_sc
 454244         1        10059926         191    ASSIGN
 471938        115       10059926         191    TRAVEL TIME
 473379        40        10059926         191    FOLLOW UP
 477652        115       10059926         191    TRAVEL TIME
 489091        504       10059926         191    ADD_ATTCHMNTS
 477653        504       10054444         222    ADD_ATTCHMNTS
```

Parameter: @attach (value=1, Label=Yes & Value=0, Label=No)

```
 Result (While I am selecting 'Yes' in dropdown)
 ----------------------------------------------
 incident_id   usr_id    item_id  
 10059926       191      61006    
 10054444       222       3232
```

My Query:

```
SELECT  incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id
FROM  incident 
where exists (select * from act_reg 
              where incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id
                  and act_reg.act_type_sc (case when @attach=1 and act_reg.act_type_sc='ADD_ATTCHMNTS' then NULL else act_reg.act_type_sc end  )
           )
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What's the issue? Are you getting an error? Are you missing the = between the **act_reg.act_type_sc** AND **(case** ?

Comment: @HannoverFist : Alter adding = also i am not getting exact result.

Comment: Expected resultset when you select `No`?

Comment: I think your issue is with the NULL. Your WHERE clause will always get all records because act_type_sc will always equal NULL. If you want to exclude ADD_ATTCHMNTS if @attach = 0, try `AND (reg.act_type_sc <> 'ADD_ATTCHMNTS' OR @attach = 1)` instead of your current AND line.

Comment: @BhupeshC : When i select "No" ,i need to get the result data without any attachment info

Comment: @HannoverFist : its getting the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query to the following :-

```
SELECT  incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id
FROM  incident
left join act_reg 
on incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id and act_reg.act_type_sc = 'ADD_ATTCHMNTS'
where 
((@attach = 1 and act_reg.act_reg_id is not null) or 
(@attach = 0 and act_reg.act_reg_id is null))
group by incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7b1e/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query that's working in **SQL Fiddle** with your data. I substituted the parameter with a 0.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f8ef/3

```
SELECT  incident.incident_id,incident.usr_id,incident.item_id
FROM  incident 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from act_reg 
              WHERE incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id
 AND (act_reg.act_type_sc <> 'ADD_ATTCHMNTS' OR @attach = 1)
           )
```

Comment: When the @attach value is 0 . What it will be the result ? here it display all. But it should not display 10059926  and 10054444

Comment: It only displays one answer:

**incident_id   usr_id   item_id**
   10059926      191      61006

Comment: Try running it in the SQL FIddle demo I set up. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f8ef/3 With 0 it gets one record and two records when @attach is 1.

Comment: Yes, I tried , When it 0 the result showing 10059926, it should be no value,

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be 2 records when @attach = 1 and 1 record when it equals 0. The act_reg table has Incident **10059926** with an **act_type_sc** that isn't **ADD_ATTCHMNTS**. Isn't that what your query was supposed to be doing?